# ¿Alguien me puede aclarar qué es lo que hace esto en un vector?

Tags: c, array

Os dejo el problema que lo he hecho pero no entiendo

> ***contador[notas[i]]++;***
>
> Realizar un programa donde se pedimos una secuencia de notas ( números enteros entre 0 y 10). La secuencia termina cuando se introduce un número menor que 0 o superior a 10 o si hemos introducido 30 notas. El programa debe obtener la lista de frecuencias ( número de repeticiones ) de cada una de las notas.

Y esta es la solución que he aplicado. Funciona pero quiero saber qué función hace la comanda que he puesto arriba...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10
#define CONT 11

int main()
{
 int notas[MAX],auxiliar,i=0,numero_notas = 1, contador[CONT],j;
 
 printf("Introduce la nota: ");
 scanf("%i", &auxiliar);
 
 while (auxiliar >= 0 && auxiliar <= 10 && i < MAX)
 {
  notas[i]= auxiliar;
  i++;
  
  printf("Introduce la nota : ");
  scanf("%i", &auxiliar);
  
  
 }
 numero_notas = i;
 
 
 for ( i = 0 ; i < CONT ; i++)
 {
  contador[i]=0;
 }    
 
 for ( i = 0; i < numero_notas; i++)
 {
    **contador[notas[i]]++;**
 }
 
 for ( i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++)
 {
  printf("El numero %i esta %i veces\n",i,contador[i]);
 }
    

}
```

Comment: pero no esta programando en C# eso parece ser C++, ademas edita el codigo y ubicalo en un bloque correcto para que se vea bien identado

Comment: En realidad es C, no C++

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente la variable "contador" es un array al cual accedes a sus posiciones por medio de otro array de nombre "notas"

A cada posicion del array contador le estas sumando uno, eso es lo que hace el "++"

---

Lo que no sabria decirte porque usas un array para definir las picisines de otro en lugar de usar un array bidimensional

[C++ Multi-dimensional Arrays](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm)

En donde definir un eje para el contador y el otro para las notas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás haciendo es uso de una técnica para tener varios contadores al mismo tiempo. Imagina que tienes un arreglo llamado `notas`, de tamaño N y te piden que indiques cuántas notas en el arreglo son igual a 10. Entonces, para lograr la tarea, defines una variable que será el contador, lo inicializas con valor 0 y luego recorres el arreglo de manera que si alguna nota tiene el valor 10 le agregas 1 al contador. Esto se representa con el siguiente código:

```
//definir un contador e inicializarlo con valor 0
int contador = 0;
int notaAContar = 10;
//recorrer el arreglo notas
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    //si la nota es igual a la nota a contar
    //entonces se agrega 1 al contador
    if (notas[i] == notaAContar) {
        contador++;
    }
}
printf("Total de notas con valor %d: %d\n", notaAContar, contador);
```

Ahora, lo que el ejercicio te pide es *obtener la lista de frecuencias ( número de repeticiones ) de cada una de las notas*. Es decir, que debes contar cuántas veces existe cada nota en el arreglo. En este caso, las notas solo pueden tener valor entre 1 y 10, por lo que requerirías de 10 variables que actúen como contadores. En lugar de eso, lo que estás realizando es crear un arreglo donde cada casilla será un contador de cada nota. Tu arreglo de contadores llamado `contador` necesita suficiente espacio para todas las notas, y como los arreglos empiezan en índice 0, lo que estás haciendo es definir el tamaño de ese arreglo como las notas que necesitas contar + 1. Luego, inicializas los valores del arreglo en `0`, y por último comienzas a contar. La parte del conteo está definida en la línea que consultas:

```
//recorrer el arreglo de notas
for ( i = 0; i < numero_notas; i++) {
    //como en este caso estamos contando TODAS las notas
    //no se necesita un if por cada nota
    //en su lugar se accede a la posición del contador
    //y se agrega 1
    contador[notas[i]]++;
}
```

Las líneas de arriba se pueden escribir de esta otra manera:

```
for ( i = 0; i < numero_notas; i++) {
    //el valor de notas[i] siempre va a ir entre 1 y 10
    //y lo podemos colocar en una variable llamada nota
    int nota = notas[i];
    //como nota va entre 1 y 10 y estos son indices validos
    //para el arreglo, solo accedemos a esa posición del arreglo
    //y agregamos 1 en el contador
    contador[nota]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El arreglo **contador** posee los valores posibles de las notas `0` al `10`, ambos inclusive.

¿Qué pasa?

> Dado que, cada posición del contador coincide con el valor de la nota:

Pseudocódigo:

```
Si hacemos contador[5]++; estaremos contando la nota 5
Si hacemos contador[9]++; estaremos contando la nota 9
Si hacemos contador[X]++; estaremos contando la nota X
```

Para tal caso si hacemos:

```
contador[ nota[i] ]++; estaremos contando la nota "nota[i]" según lo que valga.
```

Entonces para contabilizar todas las notas, simplemente hacemos un ciclo que recorra las notas como en el código que planteas.